# ASP.NET bug where to find?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a place on Microsoft Connect where i can see ASp.NET 4 and ASP.NET MVC bugs? I would also like to know where to file bugs for ASP.NET?

Comment: I don't understand that Microsoft Connect site. :(

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/)

OR here...

[Visual Studio Feedback](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/SearchResults.aspx?FeedbackType=0&Scope=0&CreatedDays=10&SortOrder=5&TabView=-1)

Answer (score 0):

In this blog post by Scott Guthrie(1) he says to log bugs for ASP.NET 4 and VS2010 here(2) on the Microsoft Connect site.

There is also an issue tracker on codeplex for ASP.NET, this includes ASP.NET MVC(3)

(1) weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/vs-2010-net-4-release-candidate.aspx

(2) http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio?wa=wsignin1.0 ( I think this is the one you are looking for? )

(3) aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

I can only post one hyperlink :(